# How to disable elevateZoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How do i call the destroy function in [elevateZoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#easing) ? The documentation does't have any mention of it , If i do a quick `ctrl+f` in the [source](https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/blob/master/jquery.elevatezoom.js), i see an option for `disable` , But i am not sure how to disable or destroy elevateZoom ?

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<img id="img_01" src="http://unilaboralgirona.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ZContact.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://unilaboralgirona.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ZContact.jpg"/>
```

JS:

```
 $("img").elevateZoom({ zoomType    : "inner", cursor: "crosshair" , easing : true });

setTimeout(function(){}
      // how to destroy elevateZoom on image ? 
,2000);
```

Now after 3 seconds, i wish for the zoom functionality not to work(I am doing this to isolate my problem, Now please don't ask a counter question as to why the heck i am doing this). What do i do inside the `setTimeout()` that the `elevateZoom` becomes non-functional.

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/z3w8hrmc/)**

Comment: Try the bottom solution here: https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/issues/8

Comment: @ClaytonLeis will look into it , if its correct i'll tell u and you can add it as an answer !

Answer (score 9):

Since Elevate Zoom does not have a native destroy, you'll have to do something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
      $.removeData($('img'), 'elevateZoom');
      $('.zoomContainer').remove();
},2000);
```

This works for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: IMO, it'll be better to disable elevateZoom instead of destroying it, since it really doesn't have any nice solution for safely destroy it. See [@Jasmeet Singh's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39996857/842768).

Answer (score 5):

A much better solution is in-built into elevatezoom:

```
var ezApi = $('#primaryImage').data('elevateZoom');
ezApi.changeState('disable');
```

Comment: I also had to hide the `$('.zoomContainer')` div since it was overlaid on something else

Answer (score 3):

You can use this. I needed to turn off the ElevatedZoom on Mobile Devices as Opencart has a Gallerybox and people can make the image bigger easily via the two finger swipe movement. So... this worked like a charm.

Its quiet simple. If you cant disable it, try to prevent it from starting in the first place under a condition that fits your needs. :-)

```
<script>
    if ($(window).width() > 769) { $('#zoom').elevateZoom(); }
</script>
```

Comment: only you will have trouble when resizing to bigger window and then back to smaller

Answer (score 0):

It just overlays a zooming div, so if you are temporarily seeking to disable it, just hide that overlaying window and then show it again later.

```
// Get rid of it
$('.zoomWindowContainer').hide();

// Return it later
$('.zoomWindowContainer').show();
```

Worked in my instance at least.

Comment: looks like not enough because using touch events like mobile scrolling is not working on images though the container is hidden